# mono.zip functionality not working as expected

Tags: java, project-reactor

```
 Mono.zip(
            Mono.fromCallable(() -> queueDao.getNumberOfMessageInQueue(cartDaemonUrl)),
            Mono.fromCallable(() -> queueDao.getNumberOfMessageInQueue(orderConfirmationDaemonUrl))
            //ono.fromCallable(()->queueDao.getNumberOfMessageInQueue(cartDaemonUrl))
    )
            .map(T -> updateQueueCountToDb(T.getT1().block(), T.getT2().block())).
            doOnSuccess(row -> log.info("Queue info inserted into db rows ")).
            doOnError(e -> log.error("Error while inserting data stacktrace{}", e.getStackTrace()));
```

I am not able to figure out why control is not entering updateQueueCountToDb method.I have added logs inside that method too, even those logs are not getting printed in the console.

Comment: A reactive stream such as a `Mono` does not do anything as long as you don't subscribe to it. Do you somewhere subscribe to the `Mono`?

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on to the comments given by @Jesper that is correct that you have to subscribe to reactive streams to bring them into action, otherwise, we are just building reactive pipelines that we expect our data to flow to.

I am also learning reactive streams so, I have created a quick example below that should help you:

```
Mono<String> first=Mono.just("first");
Mono<String> second=Mono.just("second");

Mono<Tuple2<String, String>> zipped=Mono.zip(first,second);

zipped.map(tuple->someOtherOperation(tuple.getT1(),tuple.getT2()))
      .doOnSuccess(s->System.out.println("Success"))
      .doOnError(s->System.out.println("Error"))
      .subscribe();
```

My implementation of `someOtherOperation` is:

```
public static Mono<Void> someOtherOperation(String a, String b) 
{
    System.out.println("Performing Operation "+a+":"+b);
    return Mono.empty();
}
```

So running my code snippet inside a java application will print following on your console:

```
Performing Operation first:second
Success
```

Also, `subscribe` is not the only method to subscribe to reactive streams, have a look at this document http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_simple_ways_to_create_a_flux_or_mono_and_subscribe_to_it